# Как передать массив из js в php

Tags: javascript, php, json

Немного осваиваю js, jqery, но практически не знаю php.
Задача какая, у меня дан массив "out" с множеством объектов

[image: ![массив]

Нужно, при нажатии кнопки "отправить" , находящаяся в form в index.php, передать эти данные и вывести на странице oplata.php.
Вот сама форма

```
<form action="oplata.php">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="form">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></input></form>
```

Я слышал, что можно это сделать, через скрытый input передав массив в value, поэтому занес его в форму, но ничего не вышло.

Вот как я добавляю данные в массив. В массиве cart, у меня хранятся номера нужных элементов, а в tovar вся информация о элементах.

```
$.getJSON('tovar.json', function(data){     
for (var w in cart){

    out2[w]={
        "Name":data[w].name,
        "Cost":data[w].cost,
        "Cout":cart[w]
    }}});
```

Comment: Лучше, если вы вместо картинки приложите пример объекта `out` и добавите javascript, с тем как вы добавляли `value` в поле ввода.

Comment: изменил вид массива, дабы, я думаю, к нему удобнее будет обращаться

Comment: В скрытый input можно добавить сериализованное представление массива(json, например), с тем, чтобы на сервере его десериализовать.

Comment: я добавил, метод добавления данных в массив, напишите, если можно каким образом поподробнее

Comment: Это событие `$.getJSON('tovar.json')` происходит при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Оно вызывается при обновлении данных в массиве

Comment: А почему нельзя через AJAX JSON'ом? У Вас уже есть объект... Передаёте его по AJAX на сервер, сервер проверяет данные и возвращает результат, если всё ОК, то переходим на `oplata.php`, если результат содержит ошибки, то показываем пользователю где и что не так и остаёмся на текущей странице.

Comment: Если не составит труда, напишите как именно это сделать

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="oplata.php" method="POST">
```

потом в oplata.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

прочитайте ище

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: у меня передается пустой массив, скорее всего, я не правильно передаю мой объект в input

`var jsonOut = JSON.stringify(out);`
`$('#form').val(jsonOut); `
вот мои кракозябры